# Why does app crash on Cocos2d after sprite name is changed?

Tags: ios, cocos2d-iphone

I'm taking over an app for a friend who had a developer stop working for him. We want to change the icons of the characters in `cocos2d`. It's a small running game like temple run. We had a graphic designer create another image with the same size and same file name.

We then simply drag and dropped the image to replace the old ones. At first it was running fine, then when we switched a few more, the game crashed.

Comment: can you please tell me what does the console say when the app dies. or even better post some code.

Comment: Your title says the filename is changed, but your description says it stays the same. Which is it?

Comment: its very probable that he made a mistake in sprite name or extension. "failed to load data from xyz.png" is this what you get ?

Comment: @suny I think so, because we restarted the project and used all png instead of jpg and it's fine.

Answer (score 2):

just posting as an answer so it may help others too.

What it may be :

hitting the `logs` would let you know that "`failed to load data from xyz.png`" which means the file you are referring is not present in the project which in your case may be due to excessive refactoring.
Also, check the extensions `".png" vs ".PNG".`